# Failing over to a remote datacenter - Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cluster-computing, failover

We are facing a problem we did not expect in Cassandra we have a cluster of 6 nodes split into two Datacenters. (See the image1 bellow)
http://s9.postimg.org/vyiykbosf/Cassandra_normal.png
Unfortunatly we faced a problem recently, we lost 3 nodes (see images2 bellow) and we where not able to have the cluster fully available.
http://postimg.org/image/yy3o6w10r/

On each datacenter we have a read consistency of ONE and a WRITE consistency of LOCAL_QUORUM. The thing is that we lost two nodes on the same datacenter and when the coordinator was set to the only available node in this Datacenter the consistency LOCAL_QUORUM wasn't satisfied when there was a write.

We know there is the onWriteTimeout method but we do not want to lower the consistency level.
Therefore, is it possible to switch the coordinator when the LOCAL_QUORUM is not possible ?(ie : When coordinator is on DataCenter II, the write is not possible then a retry switch the coordinator to an available node on Datacenter I)

We found the Class DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy, but I'm not sure how it really works and If it will fit to our need.
Do you guys know how the host on the remote datacenter is choose ? Where is set the list of those hosts ?

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, my first reply was deleted as it only asked if you ever found and answer.

However I eventually did find an answer.

So if you have 2 DC's with 3 nodes on each with replication factor 3.
And want to achive local_quourm should one DC fail or 1 node on a DC fail. Then you need to connect to the cluster using this

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.datastax.cassandra/cassandra-driver-core/2.0.7/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.java#172

Line 172,

```
Set "localDc"to your DC name, E.G "DC1"
Set "usedHostsPerRemoteDc" to the number of of nodes to query in DC2, E.G 3
Set "allowRemoteDCsForLocalConsistencyLevel" to true.
```

In our testing our applications switch over to the remote DC when we killed the local one.

But note: this comes with a consistency warning ...
as this would potentially break consistency guarantees and if you are fine   with that, it's probably better to use a weaker consitency like ONE, TWO or THREE

Comment: Thank you Stephen, my apologies for the time it took me to answer. I'll try to test what you are saying and give you a feedback as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the Java driver (other drivers may act differently) the first host that can be connected from the list of contact points will determine your local DC. Using a dedicated cluster instance for each DC should allow you to implement a fail-over scenario.

Comment: Thank you for answering but I don't really understand where I can find any information that will help me solve this case. Maybe I'm missing something here.

Comment: The thing is that it must be a complete cluster split into two Datacenters. Since it has to be this way, the coordinator can be in DCI or DCII (round-robin). If the coordinator is in DCII and the LOCAL_QUORUM isn't satisfied the write process will be in fail and will not be retry on the DCI where the LOCAL_QUORUM can be good here. The question is about the way to implement/set the fact that if the consistency is not satisfied where the coordinator is, Cassandra will try to write on the other DC.

Comment: Try to make your application handle the write error and implement a retry using the second, fall-back connection to the other DC.

Answer (score 0):

Implement DowngradingConsistencyRetryPolicy

http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/1.0/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/DowngradingConsistencyRetryPolicy.html

Comment: Thank you for taking some of your time to answer my question but as I said : "We know there is the onWriteTimeout method but we do not want to lower the consistency level."